# How to properly deal with temporary/useless variables $i=$j=$k=0

Tags: javascript, php

So my question is how should we properly deal with variables when coding. For example my code uses like 6-7 loops. Here is an example:

```
for($i=0; $i>$relevantnametothevariable; $i++){
    for($k=0; $k>againrelevantname; $k++)
}
```

Usually I'm using the same letters for many different pages which sometimes messes up my code and I have to figure out where the problem is and usually it's because I used the same `$j` variable in few places.

Comment: You should not have 6-7 nested loops. Try using functions, and scope parameters at the function level.

Comment: I might have overexaggerated I meant like 3-4 max, what do you mean how can I use function instead of loops. I didn't really understand that

Comment: Any kind of nested loop is a code smell. It suggests that your function is doing more than one thing, so breaking the Single Responsibility Principle.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific reason to use letters as variables. While it is generally an accepted practice due to the fact that the variables in a for loop merely act as counters, there is no reason it must be done this way. You can use a variable that better describes whats happening in the loop, and make your code more readable as a bonus.

Comment: well there is not really a way to describe variable better in the scenario I showed 
(i=0; i>explainedvariable; i++)

Comment: how about: (counterForExplainedVariable=0; counterForExplainedVariable>explainedVariable; counterForExplainedVariable++)   Obviously thats more typing, but it sure seems better than your solution of reusing variables and running into scoping issues